# How do you print a number stored in two registers (eg. EDX:EAX)?

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

When you multiply two 32 bit numbers getting a 64 bit number stored in the registers EDX:EAX.

How do you do to display the number in decimal form on the screen by only using system calls. Nothing from C.

Comment: Write code that converts the number to text (use elementary maths), then use `write` syscall.

Comment: But how would you do that, if there number is shared by two registers. I know I have to convert them to text but the fact that is in two registers is what confuses me.

Comment: If you use the division method, luckily the `DIV` instruction already uses `EDX:EAX` so no problem there. If you use the subtraction method, you will need to handle the split yourself.

Comment: Your task is similar to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285895/tasmhow-to-printout-a-register-pair-dxax-on-screen-after-multiply/