# x86 Assembly How to print a large number from two registers?

Tags: assembly, x86, ascii

I have a number 8 717 809 4592 that is stored in the registers edx, eax. The values are as such  edx = x14  eax = 4c382800  So basically edx has the high order and eax has the low order. How do I save this number as an ascii string '87178094592' without using function calls?

Comment: if you don't want function calls, then you'll have to inline the entire code sequence that converts hex numbers to decimal.

Comment: The whole class seems to be posting this particular homework question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584742/how-do-you-print-a-number-stored-in-two-registers-eg-edxeax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `div` to divide `edx:eax` by 10 and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide an extended precision dividend by a 32 bit divisor. Start with edx = 0, eax = high order dividend, divide by 10, high order dividend = eax, eax = low order dividend, divide by 10, low order dividend = eax, least significant digit = remainder = edx. Repeat until dividend = 0. You get the digits in reverse order, so you may want to push them onto a stack, the pop them off to get the digits in forward order, or store the digits into to a string array, starting at the end of the string (leaving room for a trailing zero).

Comment: Note that this will fail if `EDX > 10` (divide error)

Comment: edx is initialized to zero, after the first divide, the maximum value for edx (the remainder after dividing by 10) would be 9.